# shell script error not able to find

Tags: bash, scripts

I have this code and i am not able to point out the error. It is simple program to print table of the number given by user.

Here is the code:

```
#a function to calculate the table
call()
{
#to check if it is in function
  echo "in function"
#read from user a no whose table is to print
  read num
#taking counter
  i=0
  echo "going in loop"

        while [ $i -lt 10 ]
   do
        echo "in loop"

#incrementing the counter
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))

#s= i + sa
        s=$(($i * $num))

##printing the value of num
         echo "\t$num * $i =$s"
    done
  return 0
}


     while [ 1 ]
do
     echo "in main "

#calling the function call()
     echo "caliing call"
call()

#asking user to continue or not
     echo "COntinue.. or not [0/1] "
    read ch

 if [ $ch -eq 0 ]
   then
       {}
   else
       exit

 fi
done
```

and output is this

```
nik-pc@nik:~$ sh cd.sh

in main 

caliing call

12

nik-pc@nik:~$
```

Comment: 1) It looks like the indentation is messed up. 2) What is the output when running the script?

Comment: this is the output:nik-pc@nik:~$ sh cd.sh 
in main 
caliing call
12
nik-pc@nik:~$

Comment: Don't use `sh` to run `bash` scripts - see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: `$((...))` is a Bashism and not available with `sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, to call (refer) a function just use the function's name, `()` is not to be used.

So change `call()` to just `call` to refer to the defined function named `call`.

Note that, you still need `()` in function declaration time.

So, for example, while declaring:

```
foobar () { .... ;}
```

While referring:

```
foobar
```

---

In `sh` (`dash`), the reference `call()` will be silently ignored without raising an error and the shell will just move on to the next line of script.

Also unless you are sure, it is better to use `bash` to run these sort of scripts to avoid surprises.

---

Also there are many things that could be improved in your code, which is out of the scope of this question.