# bash and sh output is different?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have code to print the simple multiplication table of a given number.
When I run it with sh it gives me perfect output, but when I use bash it gives a slightly different output. Can you explain why that is?

Here is the output with `sh`

```
sh cd.sh 

enter the no to print table
12

12 * 1 =12
12 * 2 =24
12 * 3 =36
12 * 4 =48
12 * 5 =60
12 * 6 =72
12 * 7 =84
12 * 8 =96
12 * 9 =108
12 * 10 =120

COntinue.. or not [0/1] 
1

exiting the script
```

With `bash`

```
bash cd.sh 

enter the no to print table
12

\t12 * 1 =12
\t12 * 2 =24
\t12 * 3 =36
\t12 * 4 =48
\t12 * 5 =60
\t12 * 6 =72
\t12 * 7 =84
\t12 * 8 =96
\t12 * 9 =108
\t12 * 10 =120

COntinue.. or not [0/1] 
1

exiting the script
```

Here is my [code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748794/shell-script-error-not-able-to-find). 
I have corrected every error so please ignore any error if you encounter one!
Only focus on "\t" in output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason being `bash`'s builtin `echo` (and also the external `/bin/echo`) by default does not understand backslash escapes (`\`), hence `\t` is being treated literally (instead of tab).

You need to use the `-e` option with `bash`'s builtin `echo`.

From `help echo`:

```
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

So in `bash` (or using `/bin/echo`) you need:

```
echo -e "\t$num * $i =$s"
```

---

On the other hand, `sh`'s (`dash`) builtin `echo` by default interprets `\t` as tab, so you are getting  tab in case of `sh`.

---

To make it portable among all POSIX-compliant shells, use `printf`:

```
printf '\t%s * %s =%s\n' "$num" "$i" "$s"
```

Comment: @ManishBharti Added more info..check my edits..